# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless internet not connecting to internet intel pentium dual x86

Tags: wireless, firestarter

Everything has been working just fine then I installed firestarter and got an error saying that the firewall couldnt be started, so I changed the settings to wireless and it worked. I then logged off and had a good connection but was prompted to "enter my password for keyring 'Default' which I did. Not sure why that password is necessary but I unblocked 'Default'keyring a couple of times and , lo, no more internet. I brought the machine to the router and plugged in the dsl cable and got that connected. Also, I am being prompted to authenticate the neighbors wifi as if the system has seemingly forgotten my default settings so I have been able to miimize the noise somewhat although I still have no wireless connectivity on my laptop with ubuntu 12.10. I am also no longer able to hover over the wifi icon and access thebdrop down menu to view the settings. In the 'Network' tab, under the heading 'Wireless' it says 'Wireless' and under that 'disconnected' attempts to try to select my network from the list, restart, forget, re autheticate thus far have failed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you list the specifications of your computer, and did you at one point have wireless and it stopped or did it simply stop after setting up the wireless?

Either way check your additional drivers and see if there are any drivers listed for wireless internet.

Comment: Yes it worked from the start and experienced this problem subsequent to the friestarter error and then unlocking the default keyring? The machine is a durabook D15r laptop OEM 2 GB ram 3.2 GHz intel dual one piece

Comment: Solved.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/203562/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switchanother

Comment: I typed only the first line of code and it worked right away. The thing I would really like to do is 'squelch' out some of these other wireless signals that are causing interference. If I go to Networks and try to forget the individual networks my adapter is detecting I get interruption in the signal and then lose the signal altogether.